# Halftone pattern within InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cs5, patterns, quarkxpress

One of QuarkXpress features I used a lot in the mid-nineties was the ability to apply an halftone pattern to any bitmap import. It was unbelievably effective when printing black&white graffiti fanzines or designing one of those long forgotten fax-based newsletters : because the images where only made of solid black (dots or lines) they looked terrific even on poor quality printers/faxes.

Fast forward to now : for a few years I kept an old copy of Xpress around just because of that feature, moved to InDesign, never needed said feature and forgot all about it.

Of course, I need this feature and I have no idea how to do or even if it's doable in InDesign CS5.

Can you help me?

Comment: If you have access to Illustrator, you could [try something a bit like this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/6931/3327) which converts pixels to vector objects then resizes them by luminance (and, like halftone, is handy when you've got to make something look good under difficult print conditions)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in InDesign.

As [user568458](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3327/user568458) commented, it can be done with Illustrator. It can also be done with Photoshop. However, InDesign simply doesn't offer any halftone effects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to save the file, I think is dcs 2.0 and place in Indesing. Hit print, under the output tab there is an option for halftone. The angle is usually 22 degrees, it's universal. But its possible, I've seen it done.